# Is the session table supposed to be cleaned up automatically?

Tags: session

So we have a 20 Mio rows, 20 GB size `session` table.

Is this supposed to be cleaned up automatically and that is a bug in our customization or is this a feature?

I will run

<strike>DELETE FROM session WHERE session_expires < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();</strike>

```
DELETE FROM session WHERE session_expires < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - max_live_time_goes_here;
```

now and see how long it takes

EDIT: Warning this query is dangerous .. session_expires needs to add the max live time.

Comment: I didn't find any cron or other method to clean this. Of course absence of evidence does not mean evidence of absence, but I think you have to do this by yourself.

Comment: I see this in another shop as well :-( I guess I should open a core issue for that.

Comment: There is a method to clean expired sessions but I didn't find anything that calls it automatically. So you could implement a cronjob based on [\Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler\DbTable::gc](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0a1a283cd6a0cf4b98a051867f90150c9490fcec/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SaveHandler/DbTable.php#L154)

Answer (score 0):

We believe this is a core issue:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26308